# Nested dataset structure in PHP

Tags: php, oop, php-7, recurrence

I'm trying to implement an object oriented version of a [nested dataset structure](https://www.waitingforcode.com/mysql/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-nested-set/read) in PHP ([another description of the structure](https://www.we-rc.com/blog/2015/07/19/nested-set-model-practical-examples-part-i)). I've already created a node implementation:

```
class Node
{
    private $parent;
    private $nodes = [];
    private $level = 1;
    private $left = 1;
    private $right = 2;

    /**
     * @return self|null
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    private function setParent(self $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getLevel(): int
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    private function setLevel(int $level)
    {
        $this->level = $level;
    }

    public function getLeft(): int
    {
        return $this->left;
    }

    private function setLeft(int $left)
    {
        $this->left = $left;
    }

    public function getRight(): int
    {
        return $this->right;
    }

    private function setRight(int $right)
    {
        $this->right = $right;
    }

    /**
     * @return static[]
     */
    public function getNodes(): array
    {
        return $this->nodes;
    }

    public function addNode(Node $new)
    {
        $new->setLevel($this->getLevel() + 1);
        $this->nodes[] = $new;

        // @todo
    }
}
```

However **I need help with implementing** the `addNode` method, which should add a new node to the current one and update entire tree, especially the newly added node, the parent, the child nodes etc.

To make everything easier I've created simple test case which will check if everything has been implemented correctly:

```
$country = new Node();
$state = new Node();
$city = new Node();
$country->addNode($state);
$state->addNode($city);

assert($country->getLeft() === 1);
assert($country->getRight() === 6);
assert($country->getLevel() === 1);

assert($state->getLeft() === 2);
assert($state->getRight() === 5);
assert($state->getLevel() === 2);

assert($city->getLeft() === 3);
assert($city->getRight() === 4);
assert($city->getLevel() === 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day off and one coffee, finally managed to get this done. It's not as easy as it seems, because the whole tree has to be rewritten when adding new node:

```
public function addChild(Node $new): void
{
    $this->nodes[] = $new;
    $new->setParent($this);
    $new->setLevel($this->getLevel() + 1);
    $new->setLeft($this->getLeft() + 1);
    $new->setRight($this->getLeft() + 2);

    $rootNode = $this;
    while (!empty($rootNode->getParent())) {
        $rootNode = $this->getParent();
    }

    $rootNode->setLeft(1);
    $this->updateTree($rootNode);
}

private function updateTree(Node $node): void
{
    $startIndex = $node->getLeft();
    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
        $child->setLeft(++$startIndex);
        $child->setRight(++$startIndex);

        if (count($child->getChildren())) {
            $this->updateTree($child);
            $startIndex = $this->getLastChild($child)->getRight();
        }
    }

    $node->setRight($this->getLastChild($node)->getRight() + 1);
}

private function getLastChild(Node $node): Node
{
    return $node->getChildren()[count($node->getChildren()) - 1];
}
```

The class is going to be published on GitHub soon.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define the parent, or a reference to it, because you might end up in a reference loop, which is not a bad thing in code but in design and could end up making you code impossible to understand when things go wrong.

As for the `addNode` function, you seem to be on the right track,

```
public function addNode(Node $new)
{
    //no need for getters and setters from inside the class
    $new->level = $this->level + 1;
    $this->nodes[] = $new;
    return $this;
}
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `left` and `right` though. but I assume it is top parent is al the way to the left and the bottom child is all the way to the right. In that case I would just differentiate it from the level.

I would also not use private and use protected instead, i've mostly done this here so I can walk all the way up without the need of getters and setters to make the code compacter, but do it however you feel like:

```
class Node
{

    /**
     * @var static
     */
    protected $parent;
    /**
     * @var static[] 
     */
    protected $nodes = [];
    /**
     * @var int 
     */
    protected $level = 1;
    /**
     * @var int 
     */
    protected $left = 0;
    /**
     * @var int 
     */
    protected $right = 0;


    public function addNode(Node $new)
    {
        $new->level = $this->level + 1;
        $new->parent = $this;
        $new->left = $new->level - 1;
        if (empty($this->nodes)) {
            $this->right = 1;
        }
        $curr = $this;
        while (null !== $curr->parent) {
            //walking up to the current parent and telling it there is a new level added
            $curr->parent->right++;
            //setting the current level 1 up
            $curr = $curr->parent;
        }

        $this->nodes[] = $new;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And because I return `$this`, I can chain everything, or nest the addNode calls like

```
$country = new Node();
$state = new Node();
$city = new Node();
$country->addNode($state->addNode($city));
```

Comment: Assertions does not pass. The `left` and `right` are meant to easily query the structure in the MySQL database after the tree is persisted.

Comment: Your right, and I knew they wouldn't because right takes in account how many more are on the right and not just `6 - level` which is easy enough to do, I will not solve your code for you, just help you on your way into learning on how to do it yourself.